# restrict blobstoreservice to store the file in the GCS before validations

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I am using Google app engine and Google cloud store to upload a file in the GCS. I am creating the upload url here. For to store a file i am creating a url to host the file in the GCS. Here my problem is I have a form with number of fields. After submitting the form i am validating all the fields in the form, but GAE firsts redirects my form to the GCS and later it is comes to the success call back URL. I want to restrict GAE to store the file in the GCS as long as the validation succeeds. Once if all the validation done with the form, the file has to be hosted in the GCS. Any help please, thanks in advance. And i am using java to upload the file in the GCS.

Comment: I think you'll have to split the form into 2 different submits: one for the fields you want to validate, and, after the validation, one just to send the file.

Comment: can you tell me elaborately to divide the form into two form. I mean can i have a example of it please?

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the fields in your client before submitting the form.

Server-side validation is a good idea to prevent malicious code/attacks, but it does not mean that you should not validate on the client.